# In R how can I exclude rows based on multiple conditions and a range of values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I am trying to use dpylr filter function in R to remove rows based on certain conditions. Here is sample data.

```
df = data.frame(chr = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3),
                pos = c(10,15,20,10,14,2,15)
```

I need to exclude a range of values in a specific region so I thought something like this would work.

```
library(dpylr)
filter(df, chr == "1" & !pos %in% (1:15)
```

However my output only give me:

```
chr pos
1   20
```

I lose all other rows like data from chr 2 and 3.
My desired output looks like this:

```
chr   pos
1      20
2      10
2      14
3      2
3      15
```

How can I get an output where my exclusion criteria only effects a selected value like (i.e. chr == 1), but still retains data from other chr and chr 1 that are not included in my range.

Comment: how about `chr != "1" | !pos %in% (1:15)`

Comment: Or `filter(df, chr == 1 & pos > 15 | chr %in% c(2,3))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, you need to apply the `!` operator to the whole condition:

#### Code

```
df %>% 
  filter(!(chr == 1 & pos %in% (1:15)))
```

#### Output

```
  chr pos
1   1  20
2   2  10
3   2  14
4   3   2
5   3  15
```

Comment: Thank you this worked exactly how I wanted it to!!